# What does the "ep" capability mean?

Tags: linux, capabilities

```
root@macine:~# getcap ./some_bin
./some_bin =ep
```

What does "ep" mean? What are the capabilities of this binary?

Comment: `capabilities(7)` have nothing to do with selinux. That file has **all** possible capabilities set.

Comment: https://vulp3cula.gitbook.io/hackers-grimoire/post-exploitation/privesc-linux#the-special-case-of-empty-capabilities

Comment: @Jesse_b that's wrong, there's no "special case" of empty capabilities. That guy was simply confused by the syntax. `setcap =ep file` will turn all capabilities **on**, `setcap = file` will turn them all off (make them empty) and `setcap -r file` will remove them completely.

Comment: @mosvy: Dew hwat?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> ```
> # getcap ./some_bin
> ./some_bin =ep
> ```

That binary has ALL the capabilites permitted (`p`) and effective (`e`) from the start.

In the textual representation of capabilities, a leading `=` is equivalent to **`all=`**. From the `cap_to_text(3)` manpage:

> In the case that the leading operator is `=`, and no list of  capabilities is provided, the action-list is assumed to refer to **all** capabilities.  For example, the following three clauses are equivalent to each
> other  (and  indicate  a completely empty capability set): `all=`; `=`;
> `cap_chown,<every-other-capability>=`.

Such a binary can do whatever it pleases, limited only by the capability bounding set, which on a typical desktop system includes everything (otherwise setuid binaries like `su` wouldn't work as expected).

Notice that this is just a "gotcha" of the textual representation used by `libcap`: in the `security.capability` extended attribute of the file for which `getcap` will print `/file/path =ep`, all the meaningful bits are effectively *on*; for an *empty* `security.capability`, `/file/path =` (with the `=` not followed by anything) will be printed instead.

---

If someone is still not convinced, here is a small experiment:

```
# cp /bin/ping /tmp/ping   # will wipe setuid bits and extented attributes
# su user -c '/tmp/ping localhost'
ping: socket: Operation not permitted
# setcap =ep /tmp/ping
# su user -c '/tmp/ping localhost'  # will work because of cap_net_raw
PING localhost(localhost (::1)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from localhost (::1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.073 ms
^C
# setcap = /tmp/ping
# su user -c '/tmp/ping localhost'
ping: socket: Operation not permitted
```

---

Notice that an *empty* file capability is also different from a *removed* capability (`capset -r /file/path`), an *empty* file capability will block the Ambient set from being inherited when the file executes.

A subtlety of the `=ep` file capability is that if the bounding set is not a full one, then the kernel will prevent a program with `=ep` on it from executing (as described in the "Safety checking for capability-dumb binaries" section of the [`capabilities(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html#top_of_page) manpage).

Answer (score 10):

It is not a capability.

It means effective-set and permitted-set.

It means the capabilities will be put in the permitted set (`p`), and all permitted capabilities will be copied into the effective set (`e`).

The `e` is used for legacy programs (possibly most programs at the current time), that is programs that don't know about capabilities, so can not them-selves copy capabilities from permitted to effective.

As for why there is what looks like and empty set (as @mosvy has pointed out) the authors of the library have confused all with none (infinity and zero are two of the most confused numbers).